# Kendo Datasource - Backbone - Changes made to backbone model not syncing in datasource

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, kendo-datasource

I have a number of instances where my Kendo Datasource <-> Backbone connection is working as expected, but I have run into a situation that I hope someone knows more about.

When a model or collection is synced from the server, the datasource is also updated and respective Kendo controls are also updated.

However, if you already have a collection loaded, and you loop through that collection, making a change to the models in that collection, it appears that the linked DataSource is not getting the changes.

Example:

I have a collection of "tags" that are displayed as checkbox options. I want to display some of those checkboxes as "checked" based on other data coming from the server (in this case, I am loading a product - and want to display what colors are selected):

```
this.colors.each(function (me) {
  me.set('selected', '');
  if ( _.findWhere(self.model.get('colors'), {id: me.id} ) ) {
    me.set('selected', 'checked');
  };
})

$('#colors').kendoListView({
  dataSource: this.colors_datasource,
  template: '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="#: id #" #:selected#> #: name #</div>'
});
```

The 'this.colors_datasource' is defined in the initialize method of this backbone view. It is not seeing these changes being made to the backbone models in the collection "this.colors". I presume that this is because the models are not syncing to the server.

If I add the definition between these two blocks of code, it works:

```
this.colors.each(function (me) {
  me.set('selected', '');
  if ( _.findWhere(self.model.get('colors'), {id: me.id} ) ) {
    me.set('selected', 'checked');
  };
})

this.colors_datasource = new kendo.Backbone.DataSource({
  collection: this.colors
});

$('#colors').kendoListView({
  dataSource: this.colors_datasource,
  template: '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="#: id #" #:selected#> #: name #</div>'
});
```

So, my question: Is this the only solution, or is there a way to tell an already defined DataSource to rebuilt itself?

Thanks - StackOverflow Rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is a timing issue. Perhaps, in the case where it's not working, the datasource is being initialized incorrectly?

The code you provided at the bottom is how you should do it. [From the docs](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-backbone/blob/master/docs/web/kendo.backbone.datasource.md) you can read the kendo.Backbone.DataSource is providing the magic to get the 2-way binding. Without this the kendo ui does not know about the change events coming from the backbone collection. They provide sample code there that's very similar to what you've suggested here.

I also wanted to comment on this line:

> I presume that this is because the models are not syncing to the server.

One of the beautiful things about the Backbone.Events system: it does not require a round-trip to the server in order for the UI to keep in sync with changes. As long as you handle the basic collection events `add`, `remove`, `change`, etc. you can keep your interface up to date without talking to your server.

Comment: Thanks for replying. There's no timing issue, I don't think. This is a collection of checkboxes. The collection is fetched/populated elsewhere, and regardless of where I link up the DataSource, it draws out properly. This issue is that later, when I change a model in that collection, the datasource is not seeing that change, and therefore is not triggering a redraw of the Kendo widget.

Comment: Regarding your comment about the events, normally, the DataSource sees these events and reacts as expected. For example, if I were to add a new model to this collection (a new checkbox to the list), this will redraw properly. So while it appears to be reacting to events on the collections, the change event that the model is triggering is not being seen by the datasource.